# Basing On a style defined inside a custom control library

Tags: wpf, resources, wpf-controls, styles

I'm extending the available WPF's T`reeView` control.
I wish to add to it `CheckBox` behavior like [Josh Smith has suggested](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithCheckBoxes.aspx).

My goal is to encapsulate all checkbox behavior concerns from the end user (which is a different approach of what Josh Smith has done).

I would like to use a style for the `TreeViewItem` in order to add some properties and bindings as described in the article.
So I have created a style, pushed him to the generic.xaml and called it `TreeViewItemStyle`.

My requirement is that I still wish that the end user can add a style (for colors and theme) on his own.

One way to do that is using the `BaseOn` property of the style, but it must use StaticResource and it fails to find my style, `TreeViewItemStyle`.

Is there a workaround? Is it actually a good approach?
What do you do?

Ariel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the generic.xaml file in the new resource dictionary you are trying to create?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ASSEMBLY;component/Resources/generic.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="NewStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I had hoped that the magic beyond generix.xaml would merged it before.